First Names = These Days
What name should replace the question mark in order to get a meaningful anagram (ignoring two letters)?

"First rainbow color next to the first counting number" - Jack 

"Holiday celebrating the birth of Jesus the month before" - Jess

"Chief of the North Pole" - Scott

"Yesterday between around 00:00-03:00" - ?   


Looking at the answer, it seems that formatting is irrelevant to the puzzle. Please change the formatting to something more appropriate than code formatting (which the browser will read as code). For example, blockquotes or bullet points.

"First rainbow color next to the first counting number" - Jack

 "Red One" - featuring Chris Evans as Jack O'Malley

"Holiday celebrating the birth of Jesus the month before" - Jess

 "November Christmas" - featuring Sam Elliott as Jess Sanford

"Chief of the North Pole" - Scott

 "The Santa Clause" - featuring Tim Allen as Scott Calvin


 Taking the first names (as per the question title) of these actors, they form an incomplete anagram (missing two letters) of
Chris(t)mas tim(e)
 which is indeed what these days are.

Since we would like this phrase to be complete, with two extra letters (as @Prim3numbah points out), we want a four letter name from the fourth clue, with two of the letters being T and E.
So, "Yesterday between around 00:00 - 03:00" - ?

 "The Night Before" - featuring Seth Rogen as Isaac Greenberg

Giving us finally,

 Christmas Time as our phrase (with an S and an H) left over, and Isaac as our name.


Gur ibvpr npgbe sbe WNPX FXRYYVATGBA va Gvz ohegba’f ‘Avtugzner orsber Puevfgznf’ anzr vf Puevf…

Znlor Gval Gvz nf cynlrq ol Greel Xvyohea sbe ZREEL PUEVFGZNF?

@DanielS I suppose that could work, but is rot13(Zreel Puevfgznf Gvzr) a common phrase describing these times? I Googled it but could not figure out if it's something that's used normally.

Well done! You're correct in everything you wrote. I initially planned to write down the first name of the last one and let the answer be C's T'e which you found. So nvm, you got the right idea ofc. I'm giving you the tick since I shouldn't have switched to a "find the name"-puzzle. It was Seth Rogen btw in "The Night Before", which would have added the letters t and e to complete the anagram (and then ignoring the two letters S and h).
